# Cannot get $post object in name_save_pre hook

Tags: posts

```php
class BaiDu_Translate
{

    function __construct()
    {
        add_filter( 'name_save_pre', array( $this, 'name_save_pre' ) );
    }

    public function name_save_pre($name)
    {
        global $post;
        update_post_meta(17, 'wwwww', $post);
    }

}

new BaiDu_Translate();
```

The above code can be executed correctly. Unfortunately, I see that the value of $post object is null in the database. However, I have to get the $post object to judge the post type and other information. Who can help me, please? Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the `name_save_pre` hook, and when does it run? It's not a native WordPress hook.

Comment: It exists in /wp-includes/post.php, at about 2362 lines. Its code is this: `$value = apply_filters( "{$field_no_prefix}_save_pre", $value );`

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to get the post object. You're probably not using the correct filter for what you want to do. What is it you're ultimately trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for your help. My ultimate goal is to translate Chinese slug into English slug. Although I know that other methods can achieve this goal, most of them require multiple queries and writes to the database.